# Alter Column in columstore results in error but executes on second attempt

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

Using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise the aim is to import a 1GB CSV file. The data is bulk loaded into a database table where the majority of fields are predefined as varchar(64). A clustered column store index is then created. For the nature of the data this makes sense since values in the same column repeat with regularity. One then attempts to alter the fields to float.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE [dat].[HG_folder_3_2598]
ALTER COLUMN TOT_AU_MET_R float NOT NULL
```

The creation of the clustered column store index speeds this up as one might (or might not) expect. The thinking is that one can handle any error in the code executing this statement (with careful error handling) and determine as to if any of the data in the column can not be upgraded.

However one often gets

> error 601: Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to SQL Server data movement.

This results in the SQL Server Management Studio Query window as well as in c# code using ADO.net. As soon as the alter table statement previously mentioned is re-executed the query alters the column with success providing the data in the column is numeric.

The question is as to if anybody else has noted similar behavior and if they know more about this behavior. In particular does this problem vanish with the latest version of SQL-server?

Comment: This is strange since ,ALTER TABLE acquires a `schema modify (SCH-M) `lock on the table to make sure that no other connections reference even the metadata for the table during the change, except online index operations that require a very short SCH-M lock at the end

Comment: may be it is some other query that is running and when that fails with above error,alter works fine

Comment: Can you repro it consistently,like every second time the alter succeeds

Comment: It would probably much quicker to perform a select insert into a new clustered column store table with the float columns already declared, then dropping the varchar version.

Altering the datatype on the existing CCS requires the entire table to be decompressed/compressed and all of the row groups to be rebuilt.

In my experience with CCS, it is great for Inserts & Selects.  I avoid doing anything else with them.

Comment: @TheGameiswar- Absolutely no other query was being executed on the same table or involving the same table, that can be said with certainty. Also the problem can be reproduced almost at will. Sometimes the alter statement succeeds with no error, but more often than not the problem does exhibit itself.

Comment: @WesH- Your comment is in my opinion most apt, however my colleagues and I are in two minds; this is the core of it- To write the functionality that invokes various business rules in a middle-tier component (for example this column must be a numeric) or simply import data form a csv file and as a minimum requirement check; is all the data in a particular column numeric? If so make it clear in the column definition. This is especially required in industry in which the software is made use of (mining).